# What is the relation between Hadwiger number and Treewidth?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-minors

Is there any general relation between [*Hadwiger number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_number) and [*Treewidth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth) of a graph? Intuitively I think Hadwiger number is greater than or equal to Treewidth, but I couldn't prove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Planar graphs have Hadwiger number at most 4, but can have arbitrarily high tree width (as evidenced by the $n \times n$ grid).

Comment: Is there any general relation between them?

Comment: Hadwiger number is less than or equal to tree width +1, because tree width at most $k$ is a minor closed property and the tree width of $K_n$ Is $n-1$.